# categories not updating with wp_update_post

Tags: wordpress, categories

When I run wp_update_post, it doesn't update the categories:

```
$update = array('ID' => 1623, 'post_category' => array(219), 'post_content' => "Test");

wp_update_post($update);
```

I should mention that it does update the post with the post_content, so the post is being updated, but I have no idea why it's not updating the categories.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I would reference the WP Codex, but it's blacked out. Damn SOPA + PIPA.

Comment: If you scroll down to the end of the page there is a link that takes you to the docs.

Comment: Good call. From the Codex, the parameters seem to be correct. Ensure your ids are valid and the code is indeed executing.

Comment: The code is executing and the ids are valid. The one thing I did notice though, is that it is a custom taxonomy, but I'm not sure if I need to do anything different for that. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a custom taxonomy use:

```
wp_set_post_terms()
```

to set the category for a post. Then use:

```
wp_update_post();
```

to update the post that the category was set to.